# GraphQL Apollo Query client: Poll interval not working with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm trying to [poll](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo/) for a query that I have.

```
client.query<gql.FileCsvImport, gql.FileCsvImportVariables>({
      variables: { id: this.state.importId },
      query: CSV_IMPORT,
      pollInterval: 500,
    })
```

However I get the following error message

`Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'pollInterval' does not exist in type 'QueryOptions<FileCsvImportVariables>'`

I clearly see that there is such an option in the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo/)

What am I doing wrong here?

I'm on version `"react-apollo": "^3.1.1",` and `"apollo-client": "^2.6.4",`

Comment: use apollo boost package npm install apollo-boost @apollo/react-hooks graphql. let me know if this works

Comment: Yes, finally went that way. Using hooks now.

Answer (score 1):

For any future passerby:

Somehow this doesn't work with `client.query` But works with `react-hooks`

You can use it like below

```
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(CSV_IMPORT, {
      variables: { id: this.state.importId },
      pollInterval: 500,
    })
```

Comment: But why the query method has that option? And how do we do polling with client.query?  Currently I did it manually with interval